# Modern Page - Adding Top Navigation Links

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-experience, navigation, quick-launch, top-navigation

I need to add some links to the top navigation bar in my Modern SP Page. Here is what I currently see:

[image]

I'd like to be able to add links horizontally (rather than the vertical left-side navigation) where either of the highlights portions are.  Currently if I go to Site Settings I can add links at the top:

[image]

But the text/link appears small and at the very top of the page:

[image]

Is there any way to add top navigation in either of those highlighted sections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using **Team site** & not **Communication site**, you have left navigation instead of top navigation.

If you don't want left navigation & use top navigation, you have to use [communication site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-communication-site-in-sharepoint-7fb44b20-a72f-4d2c-9173-fc8f59ba50eb).

**Team site navigation**:

[image]

**Communication site navigation**:

[image]

[Team Site vs. Communication Site: Which one should I choose?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/team-site-or-communication-site)

You can find more information about customizing SharePoint site navigation at: [Customize the navigation on your SharePoint site](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-the-navigation-on-your-sharepoint-site-3cd61ae7-a9ed-4e1e-bf6d-4655f0bf25ca)

---

If you want to continue using **team site**, there is no out of the box way to add navigation links at the places you highlighted in image (attached in your question).

Comment: Ah okay.  I was afraid of that.  Thank you for the info!